# Reset TextField(value:format:prompt:) to the prompt text

Tags: swiftui, textfield

The expected behaviour is that when the `Button` is pressed the `TextField` is reset to the prompt text: "..."

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var num: Double?
    @FocusState var isFocused
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        VStack {
            TextField("",
                      value: $num,
                      format: .number,
                      prompt:Text("..."))
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .focused($isFocused)
            Button("send data"){
                isFocused = false
                num = nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I have to press the `Button` twice to get the expected behaviour

Comment: Have you tried wrapping "num = nil" in "DispatchQueue.main.async {...}?"

Answer (score 1):

When you reset the `FocusState`, the `View` may not update immediately. My implementation below waits for `10,000,000` nanoseconds, which is only `0.01` seconds, and therefore is barely noticeable. However, this allows the `FocusState` to change and unfocus before setting the number.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var num: Double?
    @FocusState var isFocused
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        VStack {
            TextField("",
                      value: $num,
                      format: .number,
                      prompt:Text("..."))
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            .focused($isFocused)
            Button("send data"){
                isFocused = false
                // It's async so we call it with Task()
                Task{
                    await resetNum()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    ///Reset the `num` variable to `nil`
    ///- Note: This function is async because it waits a small amount of time 
    func resetNum() async {
        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 10_000_000)
        num = nil
    }
}
```

## Some Notes

- In the example above, I am using `try?` and [`Task.sleep`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/sleep(_:)). Since `Task.sleep` can throw, I would suggest using a proper `do/catch` block to ensure you can know of any errors that do happen - see [The Swift.org docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/errorhandling/).
- The only big change above is the new `resetNum()` function - I did not change the view logic at all. Instead, when the `Button` is tapped, a [`Task`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task) is called and asynchronously resets the `num` variable.